# how to count the number of occurrences in a data（In multiple fields）

Tags: sql, db2

Example:
There is a data in the database（Each number is in a different field）:

```
1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 2
```

Now how can i get the number of occurrences of number 2?
Please help me，Thank you!

Comment: Do you want the occurences per row? or over the whole table?

Comment: I would like to select all row of occurrences 2 more than 3 times In the whole table

Comment: this is beyond your original question though and sagi's answer is correct. (his/her answer provides the count per row) but you can just `WHERE CalculatedColumn > 3`

Comment: Thank you,Thank @sagi,I solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT t.*,
       CASE WHEN t.Col1 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN t.Col2 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN t.Col3 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       .... as CalculatedColumn
FROM YourTable t
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question，I tried your method and get the error:DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=AS, DRIVER=4.19.49. 2) [Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-206;42703;AS, DRIVER=4.19.49

Comment: This is my way of calling：SELECT t.*,
       CASE WHEN t.f1wr_count = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN t.f2wr_count = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN t.f3wr_count = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN t.f4wr_count = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN t.f5wr_count = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN t.f6wr_count = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN t.f7wr_count = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       as CalculatedColumn
FROM H032.SCC_ROLLDATA t

Comment: Remove the last `+` sign, it's an extra one @bfther -> `ELSE 0 END + as Calc..`

Comment: Could i get the some row which CalculatedColumn > 3 in the whole table?@sagi

Comment: why don't you just try, and yes.